# Preventdefault link can bad for seo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I wrote a plugin for WordPress, which works by preventing the links on the page by default, and when the user clicks on that link, without refreshing the first page, it gets the url of the link, then it requests Ajax and replaces the content of the url with Ajax on the current page. Now the problem is that when I install the plugin, the links can no longer be read by Google or any other robot, and in the live test they show an error of not being available. No, the speed test cannot use the site's links. But as soon as I disable the plugin, the site can be read in live test and all robots.

Preventdefault links may have caused this, there is a solution

Comment: [Don't use it then](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/Don-t-do-that-then-.html)